# Select data from array and displaying data from another array in a paragraph - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select, onchange

How to select the property in the select, and display the text of the text[0] array and so on, I needed to add this function in this code without changing it.

Sorry, I've asked this question before, but I couldn't adapt, so I'm posting another code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>

var property = new Array();

property[0] = "Acceleration";
property[1] = "Area";
property[2] = "Lenght";
property[3] = "Weigth";

var text = new Array();

text[0] = "Aceleration is the first value of converter";
text[1] = "Area is the second value of converter";
text[2] = "Aceleration is the first value of converter";
text[3] = "Area is the second value of converter";

function FillMenuWithArray(myMenu, myArray) {
  var i;
  myMenu.length = myArray.length;
   for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myMenu.options[i].text = myArray[i];
  }
}


window.onload = function(e) {
  FillMenuWithArray(document.property_form.the_menu, property)
}

</script>
<body>


<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

 <form name="property_form">
    <span>
      <select class="select-property" name="the_menu">
      </select>
    </span>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
 <p id="text">Text</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: So you are trying to show the selected car in a paragraph? What `UpdateUnitMenu` is doing? share code.

Comment: disregards this snippet, it's because this code of a unit converter, UpdateUnitMenu updates two input with the values of for conversion

Comment: am i right you wan to to show selected car in paragraph

Comment: Yes, when I select the car, a text appears in <span> or <p>. or also how to display a link to an embedded page in html

Comment: Check solution. I this what you need?

Comment: the problem is that the values are embedded in the <option>, and I needed to use the values from the array, because my intention is to use a larger amount of data

Comment: So you mean you want to create option for each item in an array?

Comment: I need to display a text when selecting the array item. For example, you the saab array, I want to display a text on it

Comment: You wan to display all items from array into paragraph? Can you give example. Its confusing

Comment: Yes I can, I added a text array in the code for you to understand better, when I select saab I wanted it to display the text text[0]

Comment: check now updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
const p = document.querySelector("#demo");

var cars = new Array();
cars.push("Saab", "Fiat", "BMW");

var text = new Array();
text[0] = "Saab 9-3 Viggen was the jet on wheels of the Swedish brand";
text[1] = "Fiat9 Viggen  brand";

function FillMenuWithArray(myMenu, myArray) {
  // Fills the options of myMenu with the elements of myArray.
  myMenu.innerHTML += myArray.map(c => `<option value='${c}'>${c}</option>`).join('');
}


window.onload = function(e) {
  FillMenuWithArray(document.property_form.the_menu, cars);
  
  // when changed on select change in paragraph
  document.property_form.the_menu.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    const ptext = text[e.target.selectedIndex-1] ?? '';
    p.innerHTML = `<span>${ptext}</span>`;
  });
}
```

```html
<form name="property_form">
  <select class="select-car" name="the_menu">
    <option value="">Select car</option>
  </select>

  <p id="demo"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: I'll use your code as reference, bro really thanks for the help

Comment: Okay, check the updated answer to match your functions flow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a few issues going on, so I found it best to write my own related version that you can reference from. You can run the code snippet here to see if that is what you are looking for.

```js
var cars = {
  Saab: "This is a Saab.",
  Fiat: "I love Fiat.",
  BMW: "Some people call BMW's a beamer."
}

var select = document.querySelector(".select-car");
var p = document.querySelector("p#demo");

Object.keys(cars).forEach(car => {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = car;
  option.append(car);
  select.append(option);
})

select.onchange = function () {
  p.innerText = cars[select.options[select.selectedIndex].value] || "";
};
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>

<form name="property_form">
  <span>
    <select class="select-car" name="the_menu">
      <option value="">Choose Car</option>
    </select>
  </span>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: that's right, but I need to display not the text of the array itself, but a text about. For example, you the car saab array, I want to display a text about the car

Comment: I've updated the answer to show you how to show a description for each car instead.

Comment: that's right, I'll try to use it as a reference, thanks. if you can help me adapt to my code too

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to combine the two solutions (thanks for the contribution) to reach this result, when selecting the option, a corresponding text appears and it was more similar to the previous code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

 <h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>


 <form name="property_form">
  <select class="select-car" name="the_menu">
    <option value="">Select car</option>
  </select>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</form>

<script>

const p = document.querySelector("#demo");

 var cars = new Array();
 var text = new Array();

 cars[0] = "Saab";
 text[0] = new Array("<option value='/acceleration'></option>");

 cars[1] = "fiat";
 text[1] = "Fiat9 Viggen  brand";

 cars[2] = "bmw"
 text[2] = "Some people call bmw a beamer";


function AbrirSecao(secao){
                window.open(""+secao+"", "_parent");
        }

function AbrirSecao(secao) {
      let display = document.getElementById('#text')

  fetch(secao).then(function(response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(html) {
    // This is the HTML from our response as a text string
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    const element = doc.querySelector('body > *');
    display.appendChild(element);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
  });
}

function FillMenuWithArray(myMenu, myArray) {
   // Fills the options of myMenu with the elements of myArray.
  myMenu.innerHTML += myArray.map(c => `<option value='${c}'>${c} 
   </option>`).join('');
}

 window.onload = function(e) {
  FillMenuWithArray(document.property_form.the_menu, cars);
  // when changed on select change in paragraph
  document.property_form.the_menu.addEventListener('change', function(e) 

{
    const ptext = text[e.target.selectedIndex-1] ?? '';
    p.innerHTML = `<span>${ptext}</span>`;
  });
}
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```